# making post request issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to print the data received from the body yet not working. Here is my attempt ...

```
router.post('/api/main',(req,res) => {

  if(req.error){
    res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    return;
  }
   res.send(req.body.message)
})
```

on postmen Im making a post request like these: `localhost:5000/api/main/`
the body looks like these: `JSON`

```
{
  "message": "hello"
}
```

However, im getting this response

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": {}
}
```

What am I missing

Comment: can you paste your server(or app) code where router is mounted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) as middleware on your post router.

Here's the proper way to set your body parser middleware.

```
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});
router.post('/api/main', (req, res) ...)
```

You may also want to use `bodyParser.json()`

Comment: installed and added body parser as `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')` yet same error

Comment: You also need to set bodyParser as your middleware, don't just include it in your script. `router.post('/api/main', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) ....)`

Comment: There are several methods that can be use in bodyParser middleware, that just an example. The type of middleware you should use is dependent on how you wanted the response body will be transformed. Like for example, `bodyParser.urlEncoded({extended: true})` is often use when receiving a form request etc. Try reading the bodyParser documentation -:

Comment: now im getting undefined when i do console.log(req.body)

Answer (score 0):

in your index file, before using any routers, add app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded({extended: true}));

Comment: it might be that your post request isn't actually going through for whatever reason. Have you tried console.logging the request body to see if you're actually receiving anything?

Comment: its saying undefined when i do console.log